# Library tidymodels Not Loading And Not reinstalling in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels

I am unable to load tidy models library in R, I tried to re install it as well but that is not working as well. Can someone help me out.

When I try to load `library(tidymodels)`, I get this error:

`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidymodels’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): namespace ‘cli’ 3.4.1 is already loaded, but >= 3.6.1 is required In addition: Warning message: package ‘tidymodels’ was built under R version 4.2.3`

When I try to re install tidyverse, I got this error, but first they ask me to restart R and then install it and when I do that, I get error in install.packages and then they again ask me to restart and this goes on in a loop until I click cancel.

`Restarting R session...`

`install.packages("tidymodels")`
`Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages`

Can someone please help me out and Thank you for the help in advance.

I tried reinstalling the packages `tidymodels`, `chi` and `rlang` but it did not work. The library `tidymodels` till is not loading. The expectation is that `tidymodels` run in my R-Studio.

Comment: Have you tried updating the `cli` package?

Comment: you mean install the `cli` package and load it and then run `tidymodels`. I tried loaidng `cli` but i got the following error:

Comment: Yes! Try `install.packages("cli")` first.

Comment: I initially installing `cli` and then loaded it and then tried to load `tidymodels` but it did not work. But terminated R session and did the same steps and it worked some how. Makes no sense.